# Form Fields are not Editable in Exprience Editor

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 for creating sitecore9 forms but i am not able to edit the form fields in Experience Editor?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Add also some screenshots where do you expect to edit form fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sitecore Forms` cannot be edit in `Experience Editor`.

You should use `Sitecore Forms` application to build end edit forms and then add a ready form to your page using `Experience Editor`.

You will find the `Sitecore Forms` application link in Sitecore Launchpad.

More about `Sitecore Forms` can be read:

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/introducing-sitecore-forms.html

And about editing forms:

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/edit-and-delete-a-form.html